# Delete record related to another linq entity table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am creating a 3 layer program, in which when I delete a record it throws me an error that is because the record is related to another table (foreign key). I want to make a validation that if the record is related to another table I will show a message that can not delete the record, xq when I get the error or the exception the program stops working. Or do something like.

If (query> 0) {Failed to delete}

Else {Delete}

How would the query be in linq entity and in what layer would I have the data layer, business logic and presentation ..

Comment: Can show the code you have written for deleting entity? And how are you calling that code ?

Comment: Either check for existence of related data (`context.Foo.Any(f => f.ParentId == parentIdToDelete);`) or you could `catch` the exception and handle accordingly.

Comment: en la capa datos tengo   public void Eliminar(int id)
        {
            var resp = BaseDatos.Proveedor.Where(x => x.Medicamento.Any());
            var proveedoresParaEliminar = BaseDatos.Proveedor.Where(p => p.IdProveedor == id);

            foreach (var item in proveedoresParaEliminar)
            {             
                    BaseDatos.Proveedor.Remove(item);               
            }
            BaseDatos.SaveChanges();
        }

Answer (score 0):

In the data layer: Class repository provider

```
public void Eliminar(int id) {
    var resp = BaseDatos.Proveedor.Where(x => x.Medicamento.Any());
    var proveedoresParaEliminar = BaseDatos.Proveedor.Where(p => 
    p.IdProveedor == id);

    foreach (var item in proveedoresParaEliminar) {             
        BaseDatos.Proveedor.Remove(item);               
    }
    BaseDatos.SaveChanges();
}
```

In the business logic layer: Class manager provider:

```
 public void Eliminar(int id) {      
     repo.Eliminar(id);
 }
```

In the layer presentation:

```
private void btEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Gestor.Eliminar();
}
```